# Google Cloud - Deploy App to Specific VM Instance

Tags: deployment, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am using Google Cloud / Google Compute to host my application.  I was on Google App Engine and I am migrating my code to Google Compute in order to use a customized VM Instance.

I am using the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage), and I am deploying my app using:

```
$ gcloud preview app deploy
```

I setup a custom VM Instance using the "Create Instance" option at the top of my Google Cloud Console:

[image: Google Cloud Console]

However, when I use the standard deploy gcloud command, my app is deployed to Managed VMs (managed by Google), and I have no control over those servers.  I need to run the app on my custom VM because it has some custom OS-level software.

Any ideas on how to deploy the app to my custom VM Instance only?  Even when I delete all the Managed VMs and try to deploy, the VMs are just re-created by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gcloud app deploy` command can only be used to deploy the app to classic AppEngine sandboxed environment or to the Managed VMs. It cannot deploy your application to an instance running on GCE.

You will need to incorporate your own deployment method/script depending on the programming language you're using. Of course, since GCE is just an infrastructure-as-a-service environment (versus AppEngine being a platform-as-a-service), you will also need to take care of high-availability (what happens when your instance becomes unavailable?), scalability (what happens when one instance is not enough to sustain the load of your application?), load balancing and many more topics you'll need to address.

Finally, If you need to install packages on your application servers you may consider taking the Managed VMs route. It manages for you all the infrastructure related matters (scalability, elasticity, monitoring etc) and still allows you to have your own custom runtime. It's still beta though...

Comment: Thanks Vadim, I did try the Managed VMs (that's what I thought I was doing with that tutorial), but whenever I use the Cloud Shell to install my custom packages, they disappear since I'm not actually using the same server every time.  What would you recommend?  I tried Docker, but that didn't work for other reasons.  Perhaps I should go down that route and post a new question with that issue.

Comment: Well, I don't think that the tutorial covers it but you need to build a ```custom runtime```. Custom runtimes allow you to define new hosting environments that take advantage of App Engine’s VM management, development tools, deployment and provisioning. The customization is done by writing your own Dockerfile. Take a look here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes

Comment: Thanks Vadim, I had seen this but wasn't sure if it was the best option.  I'll give it a try.  I've had trouble using Docker to setup the environment I need with certain packages, but I will post a different question concerning those issues.

Answer (score 0):

How to create a simple static Website and deploy it on Google cloud VM instance

Recommended: Docker and Google Cloud SDK should be installed

Step:1
Create a Folder “personal-website” with index.html and frontend files on your local computer

Step:2
Inside “personal-website” folder create a Dockerfile
Write two lines

FROM httpd
COPY . /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/personal-website

Step:3
Build image with docker and push it to Google cloud registry
You should have google  cloud sdk and project selected and docker authorized

Select Project using these commands:
gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]
gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-b

After that Run these commands
1. export PROJECT_ID="$(gcloud config get-value project -q)"
2. docker build -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/personal-website:v1 .
3.  gcloud auth configure-docker
4. docker push gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/personal-website:v1

Step:4
Create a VM instance with command with container running into it
 Run Command
1. gcloud compute instances create-with-container apache-vm2 --container-image gcr.io/test-project-220705/personal-website:v1